# Elastic Search Scoring based on the date time fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, scoring

How to write the custom Scoreing function in Elasticsearch based on the date field

can any one help me to write the custom Scoreing function in Elasticsearch based on the date field?

If I give the date field as asc it will use other scoring function to calculate score and finally if use the asc i need add the score to document with has least recent days and if desc the score should be based on most recent days.

Comment: welcome to stackover flow, please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is not a freelancer site, first - you have to very clearly demonstrate your problem statement supported with enough code and demo data, then you also have to add the code you have tried to far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I bet what you are looking for is so-called [Function Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).
In case of date you could use [field_value_factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor). It will take your date value and transform it into milliseconds (Unix timestamp). So you should supply smth like:

```
"field_value_factor": {
  "field": "your_date_field",
  "factor": 1,
  "modifier": "none",
  "missing": 1
}
```